# Update-AzFrontDoorWafPolicy - update particular managed rule action

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-front-door, azure-waf

I have Azure Front Door WAF policy and would like to change particular managed rule action using Powershell.

Here is my code:

```
$RuleOverride1 = New-AzFrontDoorWafManagedRuleOverrideObject -RuleId 930100 -Action Log
$RuleGroupOverride = New-AzFrontDoorWafRuleGroupOverrideObject -RuleGroupName "LFI" -ManagedRuleOverride $RuleOverride1
$ManagedRuleSet = New-AzFrontDoorWafManagedRuleObject -Type Microsoft_DefaultRuleSet -Version 2.0 -RuleGroupOverride $RuleGroupOverride
Update-AzFrontDoorWafPolicy -ResourceGroupName "rg-name" -Name "wafpolicyname" -ManagedRule $ManagedRuleSet
```

I get the error after execution:

```
Update-AzFrontDoorWafPolicy : Error response received. Error Message: '{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "WebApplicationFirewallPolicy validation failed. More information \"This rule set action value is not supported.\"."
  }
}'
At line:4 char:1
+ Update-AzFrontDoorWafPolicy -ResourceGroupName "rg-name"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzFrontDoorWafPolicy], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.FrontDoor.Cmdlets.UpdateFrontDoorWafPolicy
```

I also tried to add `-Action Log` to command New-AzFrontDoorWafManagedRuleObject - in this case my script is working, but it overwrites all the rules action to "Log on anomaly" (only my particaular rule 930100 has the action "Log"), and more over - the other rule sets are missing.

Is there any way to avoid such overwrite and update only single particaular rule action?

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same error when I tried in my environment.

***The error implies that the given rule set action value is not supported.***

[image]

For `managed ruleset`, I modified the script as below with the supported type & version and it worked as expected.

```
$RuleOverride1 = New-AzFrontDoorWafManagedRuleOverrideObject -RuleId 930100 -Action Log
$RuleGroupOverride = New-AzFrontDoorWafRuleGroupOverrideObject -RuleGroupName "LFI" -ManagedRuleOverride $RuleOverride1
$ManagedRuleset = New-AzFrontDoorWafManagedRuleObject -Type DefaultRuleSet -Version "preview-0.1" -RuleGroupOverride $RuleGroupOverride
Update-AzFrontDoorWafPolicy -ResourceGroupName "example-resources" -Name "mypolicy" -ManagedRule $ManagedRuleset
```

***Output:***

[image]

You can refer this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.frontdoor/new-azfrontdoorwafmanagedruleobject?view=azps-9.6.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-9.2.0) for more detailed information.

Comment: this solution just overwrote my managed rules and created a new single rule set "DefaultRuleSet_preview-0.1"

Comment: Yes, it will create a new rule set with the given type and versions. Because the type & version which you are using is not supported. @Kosmich

Comment: it looks like a bug, according to the current observations:
a) it's not working on 2.0 rule sets
b) it's working on the previous versions of rule sets, but overwrites the values of all other managed rules.

Comment: In that case you can create multiple managed rules and pass them as ruleset1, ruleset2... @Kosmich